# PHP post foreach value to seperate array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, select, multidimensional-array

So...
I have this foreach loop with information about a product and I want to save the information to a seperate array for each loop.

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
$return_array = array();
foreach($items as $item) {
   $return_array[] = $item;
}
```

But I have troubles doing it like this since I am using input values from html and I need to add those before they get send to a database.

My foreach goes like:

```
foreach($items as $item) {
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input value="<?= $item->name ?>" name="item<?= $item->id ?>">
</td>
</tr>
... more table tags
<?php foreach($item as $key) { ?>
  <input name ="item<?= $item->id ?>_label<?= $key->label ?> 
<?php } ?>
... more table tags
<select name="item<?= item->id ?>_status>
  //Choose the state the product is in
  <option value="damaged">
  <option value="good">
</select>
```

So after this gets submitted with the form (this is in a  btw) I get something like this:

(depending on how many labels the product has this number can increase)

```
$array = 
['item1'] = 'test';
['item1_label1'] = 123;
['item1_label2'] = 213; 
['item1_status'] = 'good';
['item2'] = 'test2';
['item2_label1'] = 112;
['item2_label2'] = 1232;
['item2_label3'] = 132;
['item2_status'] = 'broken';`
```

Now what I want would be:

```
$array = 
  ['item1'] = array[   //name of this doesn't matter
    ['item1'] = 'test'; // name
    ['item1_label1'] = 123; //label
    ['item1_label2'] = 213;  //label
    ['item1_status'] = 'good'; //status
  ],
  ['item2'] = array[
    ['item2'] = 'test2'; //name
    ['item2_label1'] = 112; //label
    ['item2_label2'] = 1232; //label
    ['item2_label3'] = 132; //label
    ['item2_status'] = 'broken' //status
  ]
];
```

I want to create this information from the form. (also the number of items can increase).

Comment: Take a look at how to use form names as array

Comment: Don’t use form field names like `name="itemXY"`. Use `name="item[XY]"` instead - that will give you an array in `$_POST['item']` that you can simply loop over with foreach, without having to know the keys upfront. You can expand that syntax to use multiple keys as well, so f.e. `name="item[15][status]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
$result = [];
foreach($array as $k  => $v)
{
  //$result[substr($k, 0, 5)][$k] = $v;
  if(strpos($k, '-') === FALSE)
    $result[$k][$k] = $v;
  else
    $result[substr($k, 0, strpos($k, '-'))][$k] = $v;
}
```

Comment: I get this:

array (size=3)
  '' => 
    array (size=1)
      'item1' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'item1' => 
    array (size=2)
      'item1_label1' => string '121' (length=3)
      'item1_label2' => string '32452' (length=5)
  'item2' => 
    array (size=3)
      'item2_label1' => string '12' (length=2)
      item2_label2' => string '43' (length=2)
      'item2_label3' => string '32' (length=2)

which is partly ok. There is still 1 item (item1) who has an extra row at the top

Comment: array (size=1)
      'item1' => string 'test' (length=4)

This one is still at the top. It works perfectly after that

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks. +1

Comment: yeah, glad it helps